# How to inject mainApplicationClass of spring boot's SpringApplication?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, manifest

Actually I am more interested in 'implementation version' info from MANIFEST.MF file associated with the jar of this class. I need to provide something like default manifest servlet, where I will also have SCM commit version provided by [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/). Is there any simple way to inject the main application class?

Comment: I don't really know about the buildnumber-maven-plugin. There is a simple way to expose custom information over http/jmx using an actuator (see the 40.4 of http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html). The information must come from a spring-boot environment variable. this same document explains a way for maven to write into your application.properties during the build process (40.4.1 : Automatic property expansion using Maven)

Answer (score 3):

Have you simply tried to define `MANIFEST.MF` as property source and then just autowire values?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Value("${Spring-Boot-Version:notfound}")
    String springBootVersion;

    @Value("${Implementation-Version:notfound}")
    String implementationVersion;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("springBootVersion is " + springBootVersion);
        System.out.println("implementationVersion is " + implementationVersion);
    }

}
```

This would print:

```
springBootVersion is 1.2.5.RELEASE
implementationVersion is 0.1.0
```

`MANIFEST.MF` is already kinda `yaml` format and boot understands it.

Comment: Unfortunately META-INF/MANIFEST.MF classpath resource might be provided by many different jars being dependencies of my application. It is quite unpredictable which one will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin to create property file whitch you can simply read in spring as any other property file.

There is "buildNumberPropertiesFileLocation" option where you can specify your property file location. Just put it in src/main/resources/version.properties and read it as regular property source in your spring app. You can also specify property name.

Just check the docs for available options: [buildnumber-maven-plugin docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358051/how-to-inject-mainapplicationclass-of-spring-boots-springapplication)

You can read properties using property placeholder

```
  <bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <property name="location">
        <value>version.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

or using annotations:

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:version.properties" })
@Configuration
class SomeConfigClass {}
```

Then you can simply inject properties to your service classes / controllers

```
@Value( "${project.version}" )
private String projectVersion;
```

I have checked Spring boot code and i think that main application class is used only for logging purposes, so if You want to read it at runtime You will have to somehow inject it into application context or define system property whitch
will be read at runtime.